# NumberFormatException with ParseInt

Tags: java

The following code builds a StringBuilder, set its length to 11, and the go through each character of the string to replace it with "5". It gives NumberFormatException although the length is proper and the content too.

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
str.setLength(11);
for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++){
    System.out.println(str.toString());
    str.replace(i, j, "5");
    System.out.println(i + " " + j);

}
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(str.toString()));
```

Comment: your string appears to be null, you haven't put anything in it

Comment: Side note: Why don't you just use `i + 1` instead of using and incrementing `j` as well which might lead to bugs if the code gets more complex?

Comment: Code is a bit roundabout and counter-intuitive at first glance, but nice teaser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Java Language specifications:

The width of **int** is 32 bits, hence the range of an int variable is             -2147483648 to +2147483647. The **long** is of 64 bits with the range -9223372036854775808  to    +9223372036854775807

Change to below line in your code:

```
System.out.println(Long.parseLong(stringBuilder.toString()));
```

Answer (score 6):

Possibly because your String with number is larger than the maximum length for Integers values. Try to parse to Long.

Comment: because regret is stronger than gratitude hehe

Answer (score 2):

You know that an Integer has 2147483647 as max value? So 55555555555 will not work.
Use Long or less then 10 digits.